# How to fix ros::NodeHandle error?

Tags: ros, namespace, nodehandle, namespaces

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my code snippet of curser.h

```
  1 #ifndef CURSER_H
  2 #define CURSER_H
  3 
  4 #include <iostream>
  5 #include <stdio.h>
  6 #include <ros/ros.h>
  7 #include<string>
  8 
  9 using namespace std;
 10 
 11 class Topic
 12 {
 13   
 14   public:
 15   //constructor
 16   ros::Nodehandle nh;
 17   ros::Subscriber sub;
 18 
 19   Topic(char *argv);
 20 
 21 };
 22 
 23 #endif
```

I am getting this error:

> curser.h:16:8: error:  ‘Nodehandle’ in namespace ‘ros’ does not name a type

Could someone help me out with this please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251351/how-to-fix-ros::nodehandle-error?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's Node**H**andle

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2017-01-05**:
Thanks! It worked..